# Por que o while não pára?

Tags: c, while

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i,j;
    char elenco[30];

    while(elenco[i]!='s' || i<=20)
    {   
         printf("indique um menbro do elenco ,se quiser sair escreva apenas a letra S");gets(elenco);
         i++;
    }

    for(j=1;j<=i;j++)
    {
        printf("Elenco.:%-30s\n",elenco[j]);
    }
}
```

Eu quero que o ciclo `while` continue até que seja introduzido o caractere `S` ou até ser introduzido 20 vezes

Comment: Aparentemente porque você não inicializou o valor de `i`

Comment: i=0 resolve entao?

Comment: Provavelmente resolva.

Comment: continua igual mais alguma ideia? xD

Comment: Sempre inicie suas variáveis locais.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faça o caso normal do jeito tradicional, ou seja, um `for` e trate a exceção que é sair pela digitação do `S` logo após a digitação saindo do laço. Até pode fazer de outra forma (`do-while`), mas assim parece adequado para um começo.

Não funciona porque está comparando com algo que já dá falso de cara. Até existia um outro erro de lógica na condição.

Além disso o código não faz o que acha que ele faz. Para ter um *array* de *strings* em C é necessário um *array* de duas dimensões, uma para as *strings* e outra para os caracteres, já que C não tem *string* abstrata.

Fiz outras melhorias.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char elenco[20][30];
    int cont = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++, cont++) {
        printf("\nindique um menbro do elenco ,se quiser sair escreva apenas a letra S");
        scanf("%29s", &elenco[i][0]);
        if  (elenco[i][0] == 'S' && elenco[i][1] == '\0') break;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < cont; i++) printf("\nElenco: %s", elenco[i]);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/hSCPG0). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/gjndjmkc-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Loop/ExceptionalExit.c).

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro, você quer comparar se o conteúdo recebido pelo `gets` é igual à string `"s"`. Para comparar strings você deve usar a função `strcmp`, que retorna `0` se ambas as strings forem iguais.

```
while (strcmp(elenco, "s") != 0 && i < 20) {
   ...
}
```

Além disso, recomendo usar um `do while` no lugar do `while` normal.

```
do {
   ...
} while (strcmp(elenco, "s" && i < 20) != 0);
```

Porque não faz sentido executar o teste antes de receber o input do usuário.

Além disso, o uso da função `gets` é desaconselhado, considere usar a `fgets` ou similar.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm

---

Aparentemente você tentou criar um array de strings. Em C, um array de strings é um matriz de `char` de 2 dimensões.

Então, se você quer buscar 20 nomes e cada nome terá no máximo 50 caracteres, você deve declarar:

```
char elenco[20][50]
```

Comment: eu tinha do while mas nao estava a dar por isso troquei para while para ver se fazia diferença

Comment: gabriel tens alguma rede ou algo q possa usar para debater umas duvidas contigo pff?

Comment: @Kira Adicionei uma informação a mais na minha resposta, pois observei outro problema no seu código.

Comment: @Kira No momento não posso conversar. Você pode abrir outras perguntas para suas dúvidas, assim qualquer pessoa poderá lhe ajudar.

Comment: ok obrigado na mesma ^^

Answer (score -1):

Seu laço while fica infinito pois você usa a comparação "OR" ||, ai mesmo que seja maior que 20 ele ainda será diferente de s, ai você pergunta, mas passa de 20 e eu digito o s e também não sai do programa. Isso ocorre porque você compara o valor novo digitado. Exemplo
Digite s e está na posição elenco[0];
logo depois que eu digitei o contador "i" incrementa no caso indo pra posição 1
você estaria comparadando elenco[1] e não elenco[0] que contém o 's' por essas razões não sai do laço. Depois ainda tem outros problemas, você não pode armazenar varios nomes em um vetor, isso tem que usar matriz(array) em C teria que declarar elenco[30][30] pois se você quiser acessar o segundo nome por exemplo você acessaria elenco[1]... Vamos a resposta detalhada.

Inclui a biblioteca string.h para comparar strings e usar o memset, declarei a matriz elenco como [30][30]. Fiz um for de 20 e dei fflush(stdin) para limpar o buffer da memória em seguida, ali no "if" eu comparo se o cara digitou "s" se foi digitado s eu jogo a posição que o laço parou para a variavel "k" se não entrar no laço ela vale 20 e uso o memset para zerar a posição do "s" que não será um elenco, depois dou um break para encerrar o laço, no outro for eu simplesmente coloco enquanto for menor que a variavel k printa o elenco. Dúvidas comente :)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{

int i = 0, k=20;
char elenco[30][30];
for(i=0;i<=20;i++){
fflush(stdin);
printf("indique um menbro do elenco ,se quiser sair escreva apenas a letra S");
scanf("%s",&elenco[i]);
if(strcmp(elenco[i],"s") == 0){
memset(&elenco[i],0,sizeof(elenco[i]));
k = i;
break;
}
}

for(i=0;i<k;i++)
printf("Elenco.:%-30s\n",elenco[i]);
}
}
```